# printf not print string after \n (Compiler GCC)

Tags: gcc, printf, printf-debugging

See my code

```
char t[]= "{\n abcdeffgjejgjergnjkengkknkn \n";
printf("%s",t);

char t1[]= "{ abcdeffgjejgjergnjkengkknkn \n aaffdefa";
printf("%s",t1);
```

**Actual Output**:

```
{
{ abcdeffgjejgjergnjkengkknkn
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
 abcdeffgjejgjergnjkengkknkn 
{ abcdeffgjejgjergnjkengkknkn 
 aaffdefa
```

Can any one help me why string is not getting print after \n (LF)?

Compiler - arm-none-eabi

Library header - Newlib

IDE: MCUExpresso

Answer (score 0):

By default `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is *line buffered*. That means the output buffer is flushed (actually written) either when it's full or when you print a newline.

That's why the second part of the output isn't printed, because it's not enough to fill the buffer and you have no newline to flush the buffer.

You can flush explicitly yourself by calling [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush):

```
printf(...);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: but the same is working with other compiler (ARM by Keil)?  Do you have any reference code for fflush?

Comment: @jtro Yes, print a trailing newline or explicitly call `fflush`.